# How to observe foreign keys in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have this class

```
class User extends Model {
         public function roles() {
             return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\SystemRole', 'app_system_role_users', 'user_id', 'role_id', 'id');
 } 
}
```

Table `app_system_role_users` contains map from `user_id` to `role_id`.

I want to save **all** changes to this table.

How can I observe foreign relationship? May be there are some events fired?

Comment: You should clarifiy what do you mean by 'observe a relationship'

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

$user->roles()->newExistingPivot()->deleted(function (Pivot $pivot) {
    //
});
```

https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_newExistingPivot